# Integrating Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, desktop-application

Is it possible to create a C# desktop app and upload files to a Users Google Drive automatically without redirecting the User to an authorization page (in Google).  If I (perhaps) asked the User to enter their Google Drive Username & Password via my application can i then bypass the manual authorisation?

thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure [Google Drive](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) already has an application that does this. Unless you are looking to do more with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking for user's username and password is actually a bad practice and most of the user's won't trust you to give you so easily their Google credentials, since you can basically do whatever you want with it and not only accessing the Google Drive but also the Gmail and dozens of other services. So this is very very bad.

Check all the different approaches that you can use in order to authenticate your app with Google Services and more specifically you will have to follow the instructions on how to use the [OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I am completely agree with you being bad practice. I also would not endorse an app if I had to give personal authentication.  I just wanted to know how open Google Drive was.. :)

Comment: @user846281 What do you mean by how open?

Comment: In codeproject some one has managed to authenticate the login process automatically (which i found after doing this post).  We wanted to know if using these Cloud Services presented a risk at all..

Comment: @user846281 can you post a link to the codeproject that you are talking about?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson that is a obsolete API version